# String Input error when using stringstream and if-else statement

Tags: c++, string, loops, parsing, input

I am trying to write a part of a large code where a string of 2 numbers is inputted by the user and each number is parsed from the string to do simple addition (just wanted to test the parsing for now).

I do the parsing using stringstream which seems to work but using this code to compute multiple cases is not working. Please see code and output below;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
 int t;

 std::cout << "Enter the number of test cases: ";
 std::cin >> t;                                     
 std::cout << std::endl;                                

 if (t > 10 || t < 1)                                   
 {
  std::cout << "Invalid number of test cases!" << std::endl;                
  return 0;
 }
 else                                           
 { 

  for (int x = 0; x < t; x++)                               
  {   
  std::stringstream numbers;
  int num_1;
  int num_2;

  std::cout << "Enter the two numbers (separated by a space): " << std::endl;       
  std::string input;

  getline (std::cin, input);                                

  numbers << input;                                 

  numbers >> num_1 >> num_2;                                

  std::cout << num_1 << std::endl;                          
  std::cout << num_2 << std::endl;                          
  std::cout << num_1 + num_2 << std::endl;                      
  }
}

 return 0;

}
```

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtGuO.png)

**CODE OUTPUT**

```
Enter the two numbers (separated by a space):
0
-13120
-13120

Enter the two numbers (separated by a space):
1 3
1
3
4

Enter the two numbers (separated by a space):
4 5
4
5
9

Enter the two numbers (separated by a space):
6 7
6
7
13
```

Why is the first case not taking inputs?

Comment: Because you're mixing operator>> and std::getline() together. Do not do that. Do not use operator>> to read a line of text. Use only std::getline() for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code early in main to this:

```
std::cout << "Enter the number of test cases: ";
std::cin >> t; std::cin.ignore();
```

When you `cin>>t`, it reads in the number you give it and then stops.  Your next input is a `getline`, which reads to the next end of line...which is the one you typed after the number of test cases.  So you're using an empty line for your first input.

`cin.ignore()` tells it to skip that empty line and go on to whatever you type next.

Comment: Yep, that fixes it. However I think `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');` would be even better because then you could have spaces after the number of test cases. Still you have a problem if the user types two or more space separated values.

Comment: Thank Will. I have a better understanding now. I did not know that `cin` does not take the EOF

Answer (score 0):

First, using a value from `cin` without checking the stream state is almost as bad as using an uninitialized value. Take advantage of the streams explicit `bool operator`.  Second, you are over complicating the code, why would you read in a string of numbers, only too parse them as numbers?
You can simply do this: with an arbitrary number of objects:
`cin >> arg1 >> arg2 >> arg3 >> ...`

I've modifed your code with these issues in mind:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{

int t;

std::cout << "Enter the number of test cases:\n"; 

if (std::cin >> t) { // succeeded in getting an int

    if (t > 10 || t < 1) { // failed in getting a valid number of test cases

        std::cout << "Invalid number of test cases!" << std::endl;
        return 1; // return value of 0 is reserved for a successful run, returning zero after an error doesn't make sense

    }
    else { // succeeded in getting a valid number of test cases

        for (int x = 0; x < t; x++)  {
            int num_1;
            int num_2;

            std::cout << "Enter the two numbers (separated by a space): " << std::endl;

            // why use a stringstream here when you can get the same affect by just retrieving
            // two integers from cin

            if (std::cin >> num_1 >> num_2) { // again always check for valid input 
                std::cout << num_1 << std::endl;
                std::cout << num_2 << std::endl;
                std::cout << num_1 + num_2 << std::endl;
            }
            else { // failed in getting two int's 
                //... 
                // handle error 
            }
        }
    }
} 
else { 
    //...
    // handle error 
}

return 0;

}
```